# QueryBuilder OneToMany filter entity without relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a model

- House @OneToMany(People)
- People @ManyToOne(House)

i need a QueryBuilder for filter all Houses without People

Current not working code

```
$houseRepository
    ->createQueryBuilder('h')
    ->join('h.people', 'p')
    ->where('p is NULL');
```

always return me nothing, i have 3 house in the database only one have people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use left join for such queries. something like:

```
$houseRepository
    ->createQueryBuilder('h')
    ->leftJoin('h.people', 'p')
    ->where('p is NULL');
```